# Mysql table size on the HDD

Tags: mysql, diskspace

I have a around 80 csv files, each contains 4million rows, I want to make calculation regarding the disk size. How can I make this? I have an Idea, to upload one file and check the table size, but I don't know where can I find the table on the HDD. I'm using win7 64bit just for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate mySQL's data directory.

By default, it should be a subdirectory of wherever you installed mySQL to and named `/data`.

If you use myISAM tables (they're the default), you can do a global search for `{tablename}.FRM`.

Answer (score 0):

Get [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), it can show table size in database list view....