# How can you determine how much disk space a particular MySQL table is taking up?

Tags: mysql

Is there a quick way to determine how much disk space a particular MySQL table is taking up? The table may be MyISAM or Innodb.

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin you can see space usage simply by clicking ob the table.

Comment: The answers for this question helped me to get my solution. A thorough search for a tool that could help me without executing the same query everytime to get the data made me go through [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog), [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/trials/), [Percona toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-tools/percona-toolkit).                                                         All of them does give details on disk info,but finally opted MONyog for better graphics charts and easy GUI.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

For a table `mydb.mytable` run this for:

## BYTES

```
SELECT (data_length+index_length) tablesize
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' and table_name='mytable';
```

## KILOBYTES

```
SELECT (data_length+index_length)/power(1024,1) tablesize_kb
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' and table_name='mytable';
```

## MEGABYTES

```
SELECT (data_length+index_length)/power(1024,2) tablesize_mb
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' and table_name='mytable';
```

## GIGABYTES

```
SELECT (data_length+index_length)/power(1024,3) tablesize_gb
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' and table_name='mytable';
```

## GENERIC

Here is a generic query where the maximum unit display is TB (TeraBytes)

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(FORMAT(DAT/POWER(1024,pw1),2),' ',SUBSTR(units,pw1*2+1,2)) DATSIZE,
    CONCAT(FORMAT(NDX/POWER(1024,pw2),2),' ',SUBSTR(units,pw2*2+1,2)) NDXSIZE,
    CONCAT(FORMAT(TBL/POWER(1024,pw3),2),' ',SUBSTR(units,pw3*2+1,2)) TBLSIZE
FROM
(
    SELECT DAT,NDX,TBL,IF(px>4,4,px) pw1,IF(py>4,4,py) pw2,IF(pz>4,4,pz) pw3
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT data_length DAT,index_length NDX,data_length+index_length TBL,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(data_length=0,1,data_length))/LOG(1024)) px,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(index_length=0,1,index_length))/LOG(1024)) py,
        FLOOR(LOG(IF(data_length+index_length=0,1,data_length+index_length))/LOG(1024)) pz
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema='mydb'
        AND table_name='mytable'
    ) AA
) A,(SELECT 'B KBMBGBTB' units) B;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: `SELECT (data_length+index_length)/power(1024,2) tablesize_mb, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='mydb' order by tablesize_mb;` to get a list of all tables of `mydb` with name and size, ordered by size.

Comment: Append "DESC" to the ORDER BY clause to see tables that consume more disk space first. ;)

Comment: To be precise, You may want to call the units ki**bi**bytes (KiB), me**bi**bytes (MiB) and gi**bi**bytes (GiB) when using binary prefixes (multiplication with the power of 2). Or, You may want to use decimal prefixes (multiplication with the power of 1000) and then call the units ki**lo**bytes (KB), me**ga**bytes (MB) and gi**ga**bytes (GB).

See more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: Does anybody know how to do the same in MSSQL?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, could you please suggest on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976837/mysql-optimization-suggestion-for-large-table

Answer (score 29):

Quick bit of SQL to get the top 20 biggest tables in MB.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name,
  ROUND((data_length+index_length)/POWER(1024,2),2) AS tablesize_mb
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY tablesize_mb DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Hope that's useful to somebody!

Answer (score 13):

This won't be accurate for InnoDB tables. The size on disk is actually bigger than that reported via query.

Please see this link from Percona for more information.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/12/16/how-much-space-does-empty-innodb-table-take/

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [How do I check how much disk space my database is using?](http://support.modwest.com/content/6/199/en/how-do-i-check-how-much-disk-space-my-database-is-using.html)

> You can check MySQL table size either by looking at `phpMyAdmin` in
>   your control panel by clicking on the database name in the left frame
>   and reading the size for the tables in there in the right frame.

The below query will as well help to get the same information in `bytes`

```
select SUM(data_length) + SUM(index_length) as total_size 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'db_name' 
and table_name='table_name';
```

Comment: This assumes phpMyAdmin is installed

Answer (score 2):

In linux with mysql installed by default:

```
[you@yourbox]$ ls -lha /var/lib/mysql/<databasename>
```

based on [NIXCRAFT's mysql db location](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-datadir-files-stored-unix-linux/)

Comment: The question is asking how to measure the space taken up *by a particular table*.

Comment: @ShariqueAbdullah this will work if you're using innodb_file_per_table, which is not default, but I think its very common and/or recommended (someone can easily prove me wrong on this, just my impression).

Comment: @Seaux, May be, but I haven't found it being used in any recommended server setups I've been through. So you may be right, but since its not the default he may not find it. Also, I think innodb functions quite different compared to MyISAM. So even if you have the file size, it may not be as accurate as it would be in case of MyISAM. But you are right that may be one solution. I personally prefer using MySQL commands to get this info rather than measuring file sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the RolandMySQLDBA's answer I think we can use the above to get the size of each schema in a table:

```
SELECT table_schema, SUM((data_length+index_length)/power(1024,1)) tablesize_kb 
    FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Really liked it!

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps look at the size of the files...

Each table is stored in a couple of separate files inside a folder that is named whatever you called your database. These folders are stored within the mysql data directory.

From there you can do a 'du -sh .*' to get the size of the table on disk.

Comment: This only works for MyISAM databases. The OP asked for a solution that works with InnoDB as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use '[mysqldiskusage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldiskusage.html)' tool as follow

```
$ mysqldiskusage --server=user:password@localhost mydbname
# Source on localhost: ... connected.

# Database totals:
+------------+----------------+
| db_name    |         total  |
+------------+----------------+
| mydbaname  | 5,403,033,600  |
+------------+----------------+

Total database disk usage = 5,403,033,600 bytes or 5.03 GB
```

Comment: The OP asked for disk space of particular MySQL table, not the whole database

Answer (score 0):

Most answers above are inaccurate for InnoDB tables. You can replicate this easily.

Add 10,000 dummy records to a table, and run the above suggested queries. Then delete all 10,000 records using delete command (not truncate).

Run above suggested queries again, you will see the size is not 0.

Files on disk only grow but dont shrink even when data is deleted. If you want to shrink, you need to truncate or run something such as OPTIMIZE TABLE.

There seems no reliable way to know how much space InnoDB table records are really consuming. Even if file on disk says 100MB, actual records in DB could be 0.