# Calculate How Much Space that could Reclaim in Innodb MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

did anyone know a query that used to calculate the free space from innodb that actually i can reclaim before i set innodb_file_per_table in my.cnf, i actually found it ( two weeks ago) somewhere in stackoverflow but i forgot to bookmark it. thanks in advance ?? (and sorry about my bad english, not my mother language).

another information: i used innodb as my default storage engine, and there only one file ibdata1 that actually very big (22 GB), how i calculate the free space of this file ??

Comment: This ? [How can you determine how much disk space a particular MySQL table is taking up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474591/how-can-you-determine-how-much-disk-space-a-particular-mysql-table-is-taking-up)

Comment: those one used for determine how much space of the table actually used, i already used that. the one what i want to know is how much free space of the ibdata that actualy i could get if i set innodb_per_table in my.cnf.

Comment: Press `Ctrl h` at the same time

Comment: my wife clear the history yesterday :(