# Choosing Appropriate Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, postgresql

I'm working on a website which have requirement to store large numbers of data on single table. It will be over 100K entries per month and stores for minimum 5 years. It will approx 100k × 60 months = 6 million entries.

My Question is which is the best DBMS system which can handles this kind of data? `Mysql`/`Oracle`/`PostgreSQL`?

Comment: This question calls for opinions, there is no specific answer here.

Comment: There is a StackExchange site for this question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, 6M records is not very much, so in these days it should not be a problem for any mainstream DBMS. However, I see two aspects:

**1) Space assessment** - approximate how much space will be needed. For this you can insert in a table several records that will be similar to yours and extrapolate this to 6M records. E.g. (I have used SQL Server, but this should be available for any other DBMS such as [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474591/how-can-you-determine-how-much-disk-space-a-particular-mysql-table-is-taking-up)):

Record looks like this (4 integers and a varchar)

```
103 1033    15  0   The %S_MSG that starts with '%.*ls' is too long. Maximum length is %d.
```

I have inserted about 1M rows in a table and space usage returns something like:

```
rows    reserved    
1008656 268232 KB
```

So, it will be about 1.5GB for 6M rows.

**2) Usage assessment** - already specified by `chanaka wije`. If you do only SELECTs or INSERTs, no special features are required (like support for many transactions per time unit).

Also, in order to improve `SELECT` performance, you should take a look into partitioning (by time your case) - see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/partconc.htm) or [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. im looking exactly what you answered thanks @Alexei

Answer (score 1):

depends on the usage of your table whether you want insert only or whether you do selects frequently, I'm using a table to store web page views, 4 million records per month and I'm using mysql, also every 6 months I do trimming, no issues so far, if you want to use select queries use correct database engine like Innodb has Row-level locking, and MyISAM has Table-level locking

Comment: You can also use `Amazon RDS`

Comment: i have to do a simple insert update and delete operation no advance features required. and thanks for the ans.

Answer (score -2):

This is a good question. Apart from what has been suggested here, I think one issue to be considered  would be how you connect to the database. Oracle itself can only scale well if you are using a connection pool (limited fixed amount of connections). If you are connecting all the time, peaking some data and disconnecting, don't use Oracle. Seriously, go for MySQL.

And if your application is very simple, consider the least expensive option. Don't throw Oracle at it just because is "the best out there".

Comment: i think MySQL is best for me. Thanks for answer.