# How to calculate how much memory for database I need?

Tags: postgresql, memory

I am creating an app with a database. I found some free hosting for my database but I'm not sure that I will have enough memory for my database. So, my question is how to calculate how much memory on hard disk approximately will take my database if I know how much records (rows) will have each table?
PS: database will not have any media (pictures, music etc.) just numbers and text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more empirical answer that is not elegant but should give you a starting point. It is based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474591/how-can-you-determine-how-much-disk-space-a-particular-mysql-table-is-taking-up)

```
1. Construct a dummy table that is set up **exactly** how you want your real table to be.

2. Write a query that inserts 10000 random rows into the table.
   You can use a scripting language for this.
   For example, if you have three columns, all with varchar(100), try using php to write this query"

    $col1_Val = str_repeat('x', mt_rand(0,100));
    $col2_Val = str_repeat('y', mt_rand(0,100));
    $col3_Val = str_repeat('z', mt_rand(0,100));

    $bulk_query = "INSERT INTO my_dummy_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ($col1_Val, $col2_Val, $col3_Val),";

3. Concatenate to create a statement that will do 10000 inserts:
    for($i = 0; $i < 9999; $i++) {
        $col1_Val = str_repeat('x', mt_rand(0,100));
        $col2_Val = str_repeat('y', mt_rand(0,100));
        $col3_Val = str_repeat('z', mt_rand(0,100));
        $bulk_query .= ",($col1_Val, $col2_Val, $col3_Val)";
    }

4. Now the query has been constructed.
   Echo it or copy it in whichever way and then run the query from a script, PHPAdmin, command line, etc.

5. Now get the table size either using the link above, PHPAdmin, etc.

6. Divide the table size by 10000.
   This is your `average space requirement per row`.

7. If you know roughly how many rows your table will need, multiply `number of rows` by `average space requirement per row`.
   This your **estimated space requirement**.
```