# How to find out how much space a SQL Server table uses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to get the amount of space on disk that a particular table uses? Let's say I have a million users stored in my table and I want to know how much space it's required to store all users and/or one of them.

**Update**:

I'm planning to use redis to cache some fields from one particular table in memory to quickly retrieve the needed data after. So I need to calculate how much space approximately will it take and thus will it fit in the memory or not. Definitely it depends on the data types that I use inside my table but if a table consists of several dozens of fields it would take too much time to count this one by one.

There is exactly such answer for the MySQL though it's not suitable for SQL Server: [How can you determine how much disk space a particular MySQL table is taking up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6474591/3731444) You can check it to see what I mean.

Comment: It depends on the datatype you are using to store them.

Comment: You can't easily do this. You can calculate the minimum required size for each column and sum them to find out the storage requirement for the basic data, but there is additional overhead involved for each column and row as well, in addition to space taken for indexes associated with the column, overhead related to the database itself that could be considered part of that table's size as well, and other factors. What difference could it possibly make anyway? Your concern should be with the size of the overall database, not a single table or row.

Comment: If you have SSMS, you can right-click on the table in the Object Explorer, go to Properties, and then look at the Storage page. The field, Data space, is the size of the data in that table, but it probably does not include some of the overhead costs of the table.

Comment: @zambonee Great, that's exactly what I needed! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SSMS, you can right-click on the table in the Object Explorer, go to Properties, and then look at the Storage page. The field, Data space, is the size of the data in that table, but it probably does not include some of the overhead costs of the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an extended comment, because it does not directly answer the question.

For most purposes, you just use the size of the columns, add them together, and multiply by the number of rows.  This lowballs the estimate, but it is reasonable.  And (depending on how you handle the types) might be a reasonable estimate of the size of exporting the data.

That said, the storage of tables is a difficult matter.  Here are some of the factors you need to take into account:

- The size of individuals fields.  This is made slightly more difficult because some types have varying sizes, so those are entirely data dependent.
- The number of pages occupied by a table (or equivalently how full each data page is).  Note that this can vary, depending on how full each table is.
- The number of pages occupied by "overflow" data types, such as `varchar(max)`.
- Whether or not the data pages are compressed or encrypted.
- The indexes for the table.
- How full each index page is.

And, no doubt, I've left out a bunch of other relevant internal details ([here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx) is a place to start on page layouts).

In other words, there isn't a simple answer.  Equivalent tables on two different systems could occupy very different amounts of space.  This is true of the "same" table on the same system at different times.

The general answer when working with databases is that you need a lot more space than number of rows * row size -- I seem to recall using a factor of 3 at one point in time.  In general, storage is pretty cheap, so this is not the limiting factor using a database.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see your full database schema, with tables and columns and all fields' data types. Without those pieces of information it's just a lucky guess. Here is a helpful cheat sheet of the sizes of each data type: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012-data-types-reference/

Then you just have to do the Math and calculate the space needed for `X`, which is your number of records